# How to get sizes of a matrix inside a struct in mex

Tags: matlab, mex

I have a program in mex that takes several inputs and checks if they are proper size or not.

One of the inputs is structure  with several scalars and matrices inside. My problem is that, one of the fields can be either a 3x1 or 3xN matrix. Whenever it is a 3xN, I get a weird/wrong result.

So lets see 3 examples:

3rd input is a matrix. If I do:

```
mrows = mxGetM(prhs[2]);
ncols = mxGetN(prhs[2]);
mexPrintf("%d x %d \n", (int)mrows,(int)ncols);
```

Prints:

```
>>  1 x 360
```

Nice.

Then , the structure.

```
for(int ifield=0; ifield<nfields; ifield++) {
        tmp=mxGetField(prhs[1],0,fieldnames[ifield]); //fieldnames has the names they shoudl have

        // check if that fieldname exists in the struct
        if(tmp==NULL){
            mexPrintf("%s number: %d %s \n", "FIELD",ifield+1, fieldnames[ifield]);
            mexErrMsgIdAndTxt( "CBCT:MEX:Atb:InvalidInput",
                    "Above field is missing. Check spelling. ");
        }
        switch(ifield){ //for each field checnk if it is how it shoudl be

            // some other things that work

            case 8:
                mrows = mxGetM(tmp);
                ncols = mxGetN(tmp);
                mexPrintf("%d x %d \n", (int)mrows,(int)ncols);
                //check if they are what the should be
                break;
            case 9:
                mrows = mxGetM(tmp);
                ncols = mxGetN(tmp);
                mexPrintf("%d x %d \n", (int)mrows,(int)ncols);
                //check if they are what the should be
                break;

        }

  }
```

So the 8th field in the structure is `str.field8=[0;0;0];` and the 9th field is `str.field9=[zeros(1,360);zeros(1,360)]`. But this code prints:

```
>> 3 x 1 
>> -96713592 x 2
```

What is happening here? Should I use other functions to get the size of a matrix inside a struct? am I getting the data wrongly in my `tmp` variable?

I am confused because if `prhs[2]` is a matrix, it prints the right size, so `mxGetM()` and `mxGetN()` seem to do what I want.

Comment: Are `str.field8` and `str.field9` different only in their dimensions? Or do they have different types? I assume none of them are more complicated objects, just simple arrays.

Comment: @AndrasDeak exactly. They are just double matrices, of different dimensions.

Comment: Do you happen to change the content of the struct somewhere in your code? From Matlab's doc: `Note   Inputs to a MEX-file are constant read-only mxArrays. Do not modify the inputs. Using mxSetCell* or mxSetField* functions to modify the cells or fields of a MATLAB® argument causes unpredictable results.`

Comment: Just to be sure: how are `mrows` and `ncols` declared? Are they `size_t` variables? If yes, what is the definition of `size_t` for your compiler? (look into `stddef.h` file)

Comment: Also, do you have 10 fields (or more) in your struct?

Comment: @ItamarKatz No, they are unchanged. No,I check the amount of fields before checking the fields themselves.

Comment: @CST-Link mrows and ncols are `size_t` indeed. About the definition, what worries you? the size of `size_t`? They the matrices will never be over 1000 values and it works in the other matrices. Ill have a look, but I doubt that has any influence in anything.

Comment: What version of Matlab do you use, and what compiler? Can you debug the mex-code?

Comment: I was asking about the filed number because your `case 9` access the 10th field, so if `field9` is the 9th field you may be accessing a different element, and not the matrix.

Comment: @CST-Link `#define _SIZE_T
typedef __typeof__(sizeof(int)) size_t;`

Comment: Wait. Actually I fixed it by printing `"%ld" and casting to `(long int)`. However, `size_t` is defined as int, not long int... What happens?

Comment: Can this be a signed/unsigned thing?

Comment: Actually I was thinking about taking the true value returned into `mrows` and `ncols`. Provided that their type is `unsigned long` (as `size_t` typedef), you can print it with `mexPrintf("%lu x %lu \n", mrows, ncols);`

Comment: `size_t` is defined as *the type of the value returned by `sizeof(int)`*, and not as `int`. That is most probably a `long` or `unsigned long`.

Comment: @CST-Link as you pointed me out to the result, do you want to answer this question?

Comment: Oh, please, go ahead and answer it. I just had a hunch, I didn't actually found the answer.

Comment: Bump.  What kind of system was this?  OS/arch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `mex` or how matrices are obtained from the struct, but with casting the `mcols` and `nrows` variables to `int`.

If when casted, they are casted to `long int` instead of `int`, they right values will show.

My machine is a win7 64bit

Comment: What system are you using. `long int` and `int` are normally both 32-bits, despite the [standard only guaranteeing 16 for `int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).

Answer (score 1):

A 16-bit `int` only seems to be an issue on systems with the "LP32" data model, which for example is used on the Win-16 API.  Refs [one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) and [two](http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html).

Although, 16-bit is all the C++ standard guarantees, whereas a `long int` has this guarantee.